# Padding being added to the top of CardView the longer the text in a TextView becomes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I have a TextView inside of a ConstraintLayout (CL) that is inside of CardView (CV). The CL is the only element inside the CV and inside of CL there are a couple different ImageViews and TextViews.

The text and images are populated programmatically through a RecyclerViewAdapter and ViewHolder. When the text becomes sufficiently long in the last TextView, padding starts to appear at the top of the card view.

**Layout xml with a test string:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_directions_bus_white"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeShortNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_stopTime1TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The longer the string becomes the more padding appears.

**What I've tried:**

- Setting the padding and margin of both the CV and CL to zero,
- Messing around with the height of all the elements and the smaller the height of the text view, the smaller the padding becomes, but then the full string is not visible.
- Setting the height of the views and layouts to match_parent and wrap_content with no success.
- Setting the gravity of the CV and CL to start and top.

So, how do I get rid of the padding?

I've attached screenshots of what the design looks like

**Long string causing padding**

[image: Long string causing padding]

**Short String without padding**

[image: Short String without padding]

Comment: do you want to remove padding-top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove `padding_top` you have to change your `layout_constraint` like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/status_bar_item_background"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeShortNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" \\
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" \\
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_stopTime1TextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:
            29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:
            29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1
            :29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:
            9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29
             PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29
             PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:9 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM
             1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

@TheHeuman, 
MohammadRexa Abiri's answer will solve your problem, but seems like you could cleanup your xml file more.
Please take a look at below xml and attached screenshot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView                  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_cardView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
  app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
  app:cardElevation="4dp">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/status_bar_item_background" />

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_barImageView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:background="@android:color/black"
      tools:layout_height="48dp"
      tools:layout_width="48dp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeShortNameTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
      tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_stopTime1TextView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_busImageView"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewStopScheduleItem_routeLongNameTextView"
      tools:text="1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM 1:29 PM" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image]